# if else statement inside echoed TD

Tags: php, html

Hi and Good day to everyone, (Can't decide whether to greet morning, afternoon or evening) :P

I would like to ask for some advice or rather help with regards to my problem. I have a code which displays some number including SMS number(SIM card number) and cage number. This code was inside an echoed TD as shown below

**ORIGINAL CODE**

```
          <table style = 'font-family:Verdana;font-size:11px;' width = '100%' cellpadding = '1px' cellspacing = '1px'>
                          <tr>
                            <td width = '100px' align = 'right'>Cage No:</td>
                            <td> ".$row2['gps_num']."</td>

                            <td width = '100px' align = 'right'>Sim Card No.:</td>
                            <td> ".$row3['SIM1']."</td>

                            <td width = '100px' align = 'right'>Animal Type:</td>
                            <td> ".$devtype."</td>

                            <td width = '100px' align = 'right' colspan='2'>".$label."</td>

                          </tr>
            </table>
```

Now I want to place an if elseif statement in which if $row2['gps_num'] has 11 characters then it will display SIm card number instead of cage number. (just focus on the first TD) and if $row2['gps_num'] has more than 11 characters then the first TD will display Cage No.

Here's what I got so far, but can't determine correctly where i went wrong

```
                            <tr>
                        <td>
                          <table style = 'font-family:Verdana;font-size:11px;' width = '100%' cellpadding = '1px' cellspacing = '1px'>
                          <tr>
                            if (.$row2['gps_num']. <= 11) {
                              <td width = '100px' align = 'right'>Cage No.</td>
                              <td> ".$row2['gps_num']."</td>
                            }
                            elseif (.$row2['gps_num']. > 11 ) {
                               <td width = '100px' align = 'right'>Sim Card No.:</td>
                            <td> ".$row3['SIM1']."</td>
                            }

                            <td width = '100px' align = 'right'>Animal Type:</td>
                            <td> ".$devtype."</td>

                            <td width = '100px' align = 'right' colspan='2'>".$label."</td>

                          </tr>
```

I appreciate all the help. Thanks.

Comment: Where are your php tags?

Comment: you mean if 11 chars then why compare the actual value to 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use concatenation and a conditional (aka ternary) expression:

```
echo "<tr>
    <td>
      <table style = 'font-family:Verdana;font-size:11px;' width = '100%' cellpadding = '1px' cellspacing = '1px'>
      <tr>" . (strlen($row['gps_num']) <= 11 ?
               "<td width = '100px' align = 'right'>Cage No.</td>
                <td> ".$row2['gps_num']."</td>" :
               "<td width = '100px' align = 'right'>Sim Card No.:</td>
                <td> ".$row3['SIM1']."</td>" ) .
    "<td width = '100px' align = 'right'>Animal Type:</td>
        <td> ".$devtype."</td>

        <td width = '100px' align = 'right' colspan='2'>".$label."</td>

      </tr>";
```

However, I don't recommend long conditional expressions like that, as they make the code hard to read. What I would actually do is set a variable before the echo:

```
if (strlen($row['gps_num']) <= 11) {
    $cols = "<td width = '100px' align = 'right'>Cage No.</td>
                <td> ".$row2['gps_num']."</td>";
} else {
    $cols = ""<td width = '100px' align = 'right'>Sim Card No.:</td>
                <td> ".$row3['SIM1']."</td>";
}
```

Then use `$cols` inside the `echo`.

Comment: How exactly am I gonna do that Sir, Thanks.

Comment: The same way you use `$devtype` in the echo.

Comment: And the way you use `$label`. It seems like you already know how to use variables when echoing, why are you asking how to do that?

Comment: Yup, Thanks I figured it out. It does its work except even though gps_num has more than 11 characters/letters it still shows cage number which need to be SIM card no. <---this if for the cage of the gorilla.

Comment: I just copied the test from your original code. It doesn't test the length of `gps_num`, it just tests the value of it. Use `strlen()` to get the length.

Comment: Silly me, I thought you knew what you were doing when you wrote the test, and just needed help with merging it into the echo.

Comment: Worked it out like a super charm. I'm beginning to think i'm super noob.:P

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be concatenating strings and you cannot concatenate `if` statements inside a string.

You could use ternary statements but in this case it would probably be easier to terminate the `echo` or string build operation and use a separate `if` - `else` statement to `echo` or add the conditional parts.