# Highlight cells according to mysql value

Tags: php, html

I have fetched mysql results as below..I need to do is, check each `$row["$date07"]` value with a threshold and highlight the cell.

```
while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc())

{   

     $table_rows[$rowId] .= '<tr>
                            <td style="text-align:center"><b>'.$row['table_name'].'</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row["$date07"].'</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row["$date06"].'</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row["$date05"].'</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row["$date04"].'</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row["$date03"].'</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row["$date02"].'</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row["$date01"].'</td>
                            </tr>';
    $table_rows[$rowId]++;  
    
    
    
}
```

Here is my try...

```
if($row["$date07"]<$row["threshold"]){
        
 $table_rows[$rowId] .= '<tr>
                            <td style="text-align:center"><b>'.$row['table_name'].'</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;background-color: red;">'.$row["$date07"].'</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row["$date06"].'</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row["$date05"].'</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row["$date04"].'</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row["$date03"].'</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row["$date02"].'</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center">'.$row["$date01"].'</td>
                            </tr>';
    $table_rows[$rowId]++;  
    
    
        
}
```

As you can see I need thousands of if statements if I follow this way to achieve what I need(I need to check all 7 days and need to consider more than one day as well). So I need to find a better way to achieve what I need..

Is this possible to do? I have found some usefull threads [if else statement inside echoed TD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539608/if-else-statement-inside-echoed-td) but need to use **echo** for that. Is there anyway to achieve what I need in some optimized method?

Update:

I need to consider all below cases as well when highlighting the cell.

1)Threshold breached for one day.(Ex: 2022-08-25 has breached need to highlight it)

2)Threshold breached for more than one day(Ex: 2022-08-25 and 2022-08-24 has breached. need to highlight both)

3)Threshold breached for two days but not adjacent(Ex: 2022-08-25 and 2022-08-21 breched. Still need to highlight them)

4)More than two days can be breached.. Need to highlight them all.

Comment: `need to use echo for that`...no you don't. You're building a string in just the same way as in the examples. The only difference is you're adding it to an existing string (and presumably not echoing it until later), but that's not relevant to how you create the string or use the ternary expression.

Comment: @ADyson thank you.. can you help me with an Answer.. I am bit confused to use ternary expressions to my example. I have refereed them as well.

Comment: So ternary operators can cover the 7 days, all in one statement without needing lots of separate `if`s. However... you also said you `need to consider more than one day as well`...what exactly is the rule you have to implement for this? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: Well the ternary would be something like this: `<td style="text-align:center;'.($row["$date07"] < $row["threshold"] ? "background-color:red;" : "").'">'.$row["date07"].'</td>` - and do the same for each date. Basically you're just creating an expression which is evaluated and decides what string to output, and then that string is concatenated into the rest of the wider string.

Comment: @ADyson I meant, lets say two days in a row ,have breached the threshold I need to highlight two adjacent cells then I need another if statement

Comment: So it can be any two days out of the 7? Or only adjacent days? And do you mean if their total value of the two days breaches the threshold, or either of the two values? It's still not clear. It would be better if you [edit] your question to give a clear, full description of the requirement, and provide one or two examples showing what you mean.

Comment: @Adyson.. yes it can be any day. two days.. three days.... Please check update question

Comment: @ADyson, Your ternary expression has solved all the issues.. Thank you very much for the support....

Comment: I figured so. Unless there was anything regarding having to total the thresholds across multiple days, then you don't actually need the requirement about multiple days specifically, you can deal with each day individually. I will write a proper answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)s within the string to check each day against the threshold, and output the extra style instructions where needed, something like this:

```
$table_rows[$rowId] .= '<tr>
  <td style="text-align:center"><b>'.$row['table_name'].'</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;'.($row["$date07"] < $row["threshold"] ? "background-color:red;" : "").'">'.$row["$date07"].'</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;'.($row["$date06"] < $row["threshold"] ? "background-color:red;" : "").'">'.$row["$date06"].'</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;'.($row["$date05"] < $row["threshold"] ? "background-color:red;" : "").'">'.$row["$date05"].'</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;'.($row["$date04"] < $row["threshold"] ? "background-color:red;" : "").'">'.$row["$date04"].'</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;'.($row["$date03"] < $row["threshold"] ? "background-color:red;" : "").'">'.$row["$date03"].'</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;'.($row["$date02"] < $row["threshold"] ? "background-color:red;" : "").'">'.$row["$date02"].'</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;'.($row["$date01"] < $row["threshold"] ? "background-color:red;" : "").'">'.$row["$date01"].'</td>
</tr>';
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/NV8vF

Comment: Thank you very much. I have accepted.. Anyway what If i need to change the color if threhold has not breached. I need to change this portion as "background-color:red;" : background-color:green;"" like this?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out? That's always the best way to learn :-) . Also, if there's always going to be a colour instruction, you could move the "background-color:" portion of text out of the ternary and into the main string, so it doesn't get repeated. Then the ternary can just output either "red" or "green". That will make the code shorter.

Comment: P.S. I thought of another way to shorten your code as well and make it less repetitive - see here: https://3v4l.org/BPbQ1 . It relies on putting all the dates into an array instead of 7 separate variables, but that should not be difficult.